# .net etw Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing packages

Tags: c#, .net, trace, diagnostics, etw

Do you know if these packages are opensource? I could not find them....

Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent
Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister

What is the of the following package (considering the above packages): Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Logging (https://github.com/Microsoft/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.Logging/tree/master/src) ?

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The source code of [Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.TraceEvent) is part of [Perfview code repository](https://github.com/Microsoft/perfview/tree/master/src/TraceEvent).

But the code is not 100% complete, it misses the data to create the nuget packages and if you link the library in your application you also need to reference the `Microsoft.Diagnostics.FastSerialization.dll` from the Debug/Release folder-

Answer (score -1):

These are available on Nuget Galley/GitHub. 
Here is the link for Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister: 
https://github.com/net-commons/common-logging/tree/master/packages/Microsoft.Diagnostics.Tracing.EventRegister.1.1.28

If won't let me put two links because my account is new here.

Comment: Thanks rkg. I know that they are on nuget, but I was looking for the code, to read it.